# rails has_many setter should set conditions if specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

This seems like a bug in Rails to me, but there's probably not much I can do about that. So how can I accomplish my expected behavior?

Suppose we have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :awesome_friends, :class_name => "Friend", :conditions => {:awesome => true}
end
```

And execute the code:

```
>> my_user.awesome_friends << Friend.new(:name=>'jim')
```

Afterwards, when I inspect this friend object, I see that the user_id field is populated. But I would also expect to see the "awesome" column set to 'true', which it is not.

Furthermore, if I execute the following from the console:

```
>> my_user.awesome_friends << Friend.new(:name=>'jim')
>> my_user.awesome_friends
= [#<Friend id:1, name:"jim", awesome:nil>]
# Quit and restart the console
>> my_user.awesome_friends
= []
```

Any thoughts on this? I suppose the conditions hash could be arbitrarily complex, making integration into the setter impossible. But in a way it feels like by default we are passing the condition ":user_id => self.id", and that gets set, so shouldn't others?

Thanks,
Mike

**EDIT:**

I found that there are callbacks for has_many, so I think I might define the relationship like this:

```
has_many :awesome_friends,
         :class_name => "Friend",
         :conditions => {:awesome => true},
         :before_add => Proc.new{|p,c| c.awesome = true},
         :before_remove => Proc.new{|p,c| c.awesome = false}
```

Although, it's starting to feel like maybe I'm just implementing some other, existing design pattern. Maybe I should subclass AwesomeFriend < Friend? Ultimately I need a couple of these has_many relationships, and subclassing get's messy with all the extra files..

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, thanks to everyone who commented! I ultimately wrapped up the method above into a nice little ActiveRecord extension, 'has_many_of_type'. Which works like follows:

```
has_many_of_type :awesome_friends, :class_name => "Friend", :type=>:awesome
```

Which just translates to has_many with the appropriate conditions, before_add, and before_remove params (and it assumes the existence of a column named friend_type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use:

`my_user.awesome_friends.create(:name=>'jim')` or `my_user.awesome_friends.build(:name=>'jim')`

**In documentation:**
has_many (:conditions)

Record creations from the association are scoped if a hash is used. has_many :posts, :conditions => {:published => true} will create published posts with @blog.posts.create or @blog.posts.build.

Comment: Nice! I forgot about this. Although it doesn't solve the problem of adding/removing an existing Friend. Thanks though, I'll probably use this for my implementation.

Comment: Yeah. I don't think it's ever going to modify an existing object when you add it to a collection other than to set the foreign key.

Comment: Accepted this because it was the best solution to the problem I posed. However, see the edits in the question for the final implementation.

Comment: I would create add_to_awesome_friends and remove_from_awesome_friends methods and put into it logic by use of existing "Friend" object.

Answer (score 1):

It's `:class_name` rather than `:class`, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug I don't think.  The :conditions hash only deterimines how you query for the objects.  But I don't think it's rational to just assume that any object you stuff in the collection could be *made* to conform to the conditions.

In your simple example it makes sense, but you could also put more complex logic in there.

The documentation seems pretty clear on this as well:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> `:conditions`
>
> Specify the conditions that the associated object must meet in order to be included as a `WHERE` SQL fragment, such as `authorized = 1`.

Comment: I agree the documentation is pretty clear, that was the first thing I checked. But in practice it doesn't really make sense to me. I guess I just need to be careful to set the appropriate fields in my "Friend" object before adding to the collection.

Comment: In this case I'd favor creating an add_friend method which does the logic for you.